# add trace in Plotly won't plot the right colour

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I am trying to make a contour plot and draw a line on top of it (which I can do). I then overlaid two other lines using add_trace. For some reason the two lines I add using add_trace comes out orange instead of grey even though I specify grey (line = list(color = 'grey', )

I don't know how to add my data, it is very big. Is there any obvious reason as to why the colour changes to orange? If I change the width or the dash, it works. it just doesn't want to use the grey colour!

Thank you

```
 (plot <- plot_ly(df, x = ~A, y = ~B, z = ~Difference, zauto = FALSE, zmin = -250, zmax = 250,
                                          type="contour",  
                                          colorbar = list(title = "", titleside='right',
                                                          tickvals=c(-250, -200, -150, -100, -50, 0, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250), len = 1),
                                          colorscale = "RdBu", 
                                          contours = list(start = 0, end = 0, coloring='heatmap', coloring='lines'),
                                          line = list(color = 'black', width = 2)) %>%
   add_trace(z = df$C, showscale = FALSE, line = list(color = 'grey', width = 2, dash = 'dash'), contours = list(start = 0, end = 0, coloring='lines')) %>%
   add_trace(z = df$C, showscale = FALSE, line = list(color = 'grey', width = 2, dash = 'solid'), contours = list(start = 0, end = 0, coloring='lines')) %>%
   layout(margin = list(l = 50, r = 70, b = 50, t = 50, pad = 4),
     title = "", xaxis = x, yaxis = list(title = ""), font=t))
```

Comment: You can use `dput(head(df, 100))` to share your data - or create a dummy `data.frame`.

Comment: The limit is 30 thousand characters and if I use put(head(df, 50)) I have almost 70 thousand characters. Can I link it via Dropbox or the likes?

Comment: Please see my answer below - just try to use dummy data if your actual data isn't suitable.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem in your above code is, that you aren't specifiying the trace type. Accordingly `plot_ly` assumes that you are adding two more contour traces. Those traces are inheriting the colorscale you defined.

To avoid this you need to specify `type = "scatter", mode = "lines", inherit = FALSE`.

I made a simple example based on [this](https://plotly.com/r/contour-plots/#set-x-and-y-coordinates).

```
library(plotly)

fig <- plot_ly(
  x = c(-9, -6, -5, -3, -1), 
  y = c(0, 1, 4, 5, 7), 
  z = matrix(c(10, 10.625, 12.5, 15.625, 20, 5.625, 6.25, 8.125, 11.25, 15.625, 2.5, 3.125, 5, 8.125, 12.5, 0.625, 1.25, 3.125,
               6.25, 10.625, 0, 0.625, 2.5, 5.625, 10), nrow = 5, ncol = 5), 
  type = "contour", colorbar = list(title = "", titleside='right'),
  colorscale = "RdBu", 
  line = list(color = 'black', width = 2)) %>% 
  add_trace(x = -1:-7, y = 1:7, type = "scatter", mode = "lines", line = list(color = 'lightgreen', width = 2, dash = 'solid'), inherit = FALSE)

fig
```

[image: result]

Comment: thank you, and thank you for the dummy data too. I tried with my data and the two orange lines disappeared. I wonder if its because the two that I am trying to add_trace are also contour plots. I just do not want the background colour scheme of the contour plots and instead I want the only want one line plot. I have it like this now and both the orange lines disappeared.     add_trace(z = fixedPAR$Diff_growth, showscale = FALSE, type = "scatter", mode = "lines", line = list(color = 'grey', width = 2, dash = 'dash'), contours = list(start = 0, end = 0), inherit = FALSE ) %>%